# How to run a single specific test case when using protractor

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, protractor

I am using protractor for angular js testing in my app and have around 19 test cases at the moment, of which one of them is failing

```
describe('Login page', function() {

beforeEach(function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  ptor = protractor.getInstance();
});

it('should contain navigation items', function(){
  //test case code here
});

it('should login the user successfully', function(){ 
  //test case code here
})
});
```

Currently, I run all the test cases. But, how can I run just one test case to debug an issue for example one which is described as "Login page should login the user successfully"?

Comment: I figured out that we would be able to run specs in a single file using --specs option from protractor. Is there any way we could run just a single test case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The most recent version (at least) of Protractor supports the usual Jasmine way of doing that: rename a `describe()` function to `ddescribe()`, and only the tests inside it will run. Or rename an `it()` function to `iit()`, and only this test will run.

Comment: thank you! it  worked for me. But, one issue which I did see is that when I run the tests, it actually executes only one test case. I can say this from the assertions count and looking at the UI. But, the report shows that it did run all the tests in the suite.

Comment: for example: my report says "8 tests, 1 assertion, 0 failures" when I have a iit for one of the test case and "8 tests, 20 assertions, 0 failures" when I run all of them without having a iit. Is there any way that we could make the no of tests to be shown as "1 test, 1 assertion 0 failures" when we add a iit?

Comment: I guess you should file a bug to protractor.

Comment: even after adding ddescribe, protractor is running all the specs in y suite. Any ideas .. ??

Comment: Wow this is like super awful and unexpected to me... but it works :) Thanks!

Comment: For anyone using jasmine 2.1 or newer look at Justin's answer.  You now use fit and fdescribe.

Answer (score 45):

Jasmine added `fit` and `fdescribe` in 2.1 for running single tests or describe blocks.

http://pivotallabs.com/new-key-features-jasmine-2-1/

> This feature almost made it in the 2.0 release. Now enough of this
>   functionality is present to support fit and fdescribe for focused spec
>   and suite running.

from 2.1 git lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js

```
var jasmineInterface = {
describe: function(description, specDefinitions) {
  return env.describe(description, specDefinitions);
},

xdescribe: function(description, specDefinitions) {
  return env.xdescribe(description, specDefinitions);
},

fdescribe: function(description, specDefinitions) {
  return env.fdescribe(description, specDefinitions);
},

it: function() {
  return env.it.apply(env, arguments);
},

xit: function() {
  return env.xit.apply(env, arguments);
},

fit: function() {
  return env.fit.apply(env, arguments);
},
```

Comment: the accepted answer and question are old, they are for jasmine 1.x

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should separate the tests into different suites. Then you can just run:
  protractor test/protractor-conf.js --suite example

Answer (score 0):

You can use --grep.

`protractor conf.js --grep='name of your test case'`