# Running single protractor test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

In my old C# selenium project (with specflow), I used Test Explorer to view all tests and can select any single test to run.

With the protractor, is there any option with running single test with unit test explorer?

I found similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536865/2388556) from search result and just wanted to check to see if you guys have any other suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For `jasmine-1.x`, yes, it is `ddescribe` and `iit`.

For `jasmine-2.x`, it is [`fdescribe` and `fit`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html).

Comment: Thanks @alecxe. Do you know if there is a way to view of test in like test explorer or unit test session explorer like [this](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/ResharperTestSession.png)

Comment: @user2388556 well, there are multiple options. One would just involve using webstorm for running your tests. The other would require a reporter - I'm using [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter). Hope that helps.