# Protractor: run tests without changes in configuration file

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I write and run my tests in Idea. But it isn't very comfortable, because I always should change spec-names in configuration file and edit configuration in Idea when I change configuration file.
I really want to find a method to run my test without changing configs. Maybe by double click (it is a dream!) or by changing something in config.
Does anybody know how I can to do it? Or it is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the ["Focused Specs"](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html) Jasmine feature.

No need for config changes, just mark the tests you want to run with `fdescribe`/`fit`.

There are also things like [`xdescribe`/`xit`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Disabling_Suites) and [`pending`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs) that you may find useful.

---

Also, in order to avoid accidentally committing `fdescribe`s or `fit`s to the code repository, we've used [`eslint`](http://eslint.org/) and [`eslint-plugin-jasmine`](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine) plugin to catch these problems during a static code analysis step. Sample output:

```
test/e2e/specs/test.spec.js
  5:0  error  Unexpected fdescribe  jasmine/no-focused-tests
```

Comment: Depending on version of built-in Jasmine it can be not `fdescribe`/`fit`, but `ddescribe`/`iit`.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/164) topic they discuss this question and it seems no to be easily doable, but you can dig more.

What you can do is add --suite option to the run configuration (in Idea its called "application parameters" under Run/Debug Configurations if you're using node to run e2e), e.g.

```
--suite=views
```

You can even make separate run configs to just run specific suites, and make specific suites to only hold single file, which would effectively sort of work like you want it to.

As far as I know, you can't run individual tests that way, you need to change test file in the suite config. You should be able to comment and uncomment files with no problem, so it shouldn't be that big of a nuisance, but you can also try to write external script or tool to automatize it for you.

EDIT: You can also try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536572/how-to-run-a-single-specific-test-case-when-using-protractor) if youre using expect/it etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I believe that the [grunt-protractor-runner](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner) grunt plugin would let you run different tests and different options via the command line.

this is an example of how you could run your tests from the command line:

```
grunt protractor --specs=specs/some-test.js
```

There are many tutorials on setting up grunt with protractor.

---

also you don't have to do just a single test. you can specify like below

**Multiple Individual specs:**

```
grunt protractor  -specs=tests/barret/Smoke_Create_Course_2Plus_TxtBook_spec.js,tests/barret/Smoke_Create_Course_eBook_TxtBook_spec.js,tests/barret/Smoke_Create_Course_Meet_Days_spec.js
```

**Multiple Folders containing specs:**

```
grunt protractor -specs=tests/barret/*.js,tests/barret/with_textbook/*.js,tests/barret/no_textbook/*.js
```

---

additionally you can use suites as well.