# Is there any way to run alternate 'it' block in protractor script?If we can do then how?

Tags: protractor

I have 100 test cases in my script and I want to run only alternate test cases ('it' blocks).So how I will do it?I have to use 'if' condition or something else solution?

Comment: Are you saying you a have a single test with 100 it blocks? Are they divided into Describes or all part of a single describe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a single specific test case when using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536572/how-to-run-a-single-specific-test-case-when-using-protractor)

Comment: yes, In one describe  100 'it' block and they are not dependent on another 'it' block

Comment: Are you trying to skip tests at random or given certain conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run only particular set of tests you can add `f` prefix to `it` or `describe` blocs - `fit`, `fdescribe`. But this is kinda quick solution just for debug purposes.

Another solution is protractor [suites](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/docs/page-objects.md#configuring-test-suites)

```
 suites: {
    homepage: 'tests/e2e/homepage/**/*Spec.js',
    search: ['tests/e2e/contact_search/**/*Spec.js',
      'tests/e2e/venue_search/**/*Spec.js']
  },
```

Create a named suite and add files to it. Then you can run them independently

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --suite homepage
```